Choose and snooze
What nine-letter answer is hidden below? Explain your reasoning.



The hidden answer is:

 LIGHTS OUT

To find this...

 ...first work out which light bulbs are connected to each other by the black 'wires' leading from their bases. White circles act as circuit-blockers, forcing dead-ends.

 By doing this, we can separate the grid into 9 separate sections, or circuits - 4 of individual bulbs (indicated by red boxes in the diagram below), 2 connecting a pair of bulbs (green, and light blue), 1 connecting 3 bulbs (blue), 1 connecting 5 bulbs (purple), and the largest group comprising 9 connected bulbs (pink).



To extract the final answer...

 ...focus on the largest group of 9 bulbs. Look at the letters corresponding to these occupied cells in the other grid (shaded pink in the diagram above), which contain the letters U, S, L, T, H, T, I, O, and G, reading left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

 This doesn't make a lot of sense in this ordering, but they do form an appropriate anagram when rearranged: LIGHTS OUT! Not only is this apt because the puzzle grid portrays the 5x5 arrangement of cells in the Lights Out electronic game, but this works with the title too, as 'lights out' is the moment in a day when you switch everything off to go to bed for a snooze!


Ah beat me to it rats!

My answer was slightly different, basically only leave the 3rd top switch on from the left and leave the rest off

Well done! My idea was to choose one lightbulb of the group of nine and then remove it from the socket which would make the group go off.
